# Disable axis by default in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to disable axis by default (or in one session) in Matplotlib 2.0

I've been searching it and so far I found the `plt.axis('off')`. For example.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
img = plt.imread('image.png')
plt.imshow(img)
plt.axis('off')
```

But how to set it to default like in `rcParams` ? I haven't found anything related to `axis('off')` in the dictionary.

Comment: It's not duplicate, since the question is only about one figure and multiple subplots, but the answer did answer my question.

Comment: It's not clean though since we just change the color of the axis and ticks to white. Probably there's going to be a better answer out there.